# Get clicked anchor text to referring page using php

Tags: anchor, title

WordPress: **PHP**, 
I want to get text between "a" tag in the referring page. Like:

I have below link on **Page 1**: `http://somesite.com/page1`

```
<a href="http://somesite.com/page2"> Aminul Islam</a>
```

I want to print "**Aminul Islam**" on **Page 2** ( `http://somesite.com/page2` )

Answer (score 0):

You can use java script or jQuery: for that:

Example:

```js
//java script
var linktext = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
          console.log(linktext[0].text);    

     
//Jquery              
$(document).ready(function(){
  var linktext=$('a').text();
  console.log(linktext);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://somesite.com/name"> Aminul Islam</a>
```

And with PHP:

```php
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node)
{
  echo $node->nodeValue.': '.$node->getAttribute("href")."\n";
}
```

Comment: Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Empty string supplied as input